# Python Request send image

Tags: python, request

I have a fastapi app where one of my endpoints reads as:

```
@app.post(
"/testing", 
name="testing", 
tags=["pluggin"],
)
def testing(images: List[bytes] = File(...)):
    #do whatever
```

how can I send a request with an image so the endpoint will read it correctly? Right now I have:

```
import requests

f = io.BytesIO(file readed in binary)
files = {'file': f.getvalue()}
r = requests.post("mywebsite:myport/testing", files=files)
```

but it returns me response 422

Comment: you can use postman to test this api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `requests` payload must contains the same name as in the function parameter(`images`).

This means,

```
def testing(images: List[bytes] = File(...)):
            ^^^^^^^
```

and

```
files = {'file': f.getvalue()}
         ^^^^^^
```

must be same. So changing your code to following will work as expected.

```
import requests

f = io.BytesIO(file readed in binary)
files = {'images': f.getvalue()}
          ^^^^^
r = requests.post("mywebsite:myport/testing", files=files)
```